# how to get whole value for using hashmap in android?

Tags: java, android, hashmap, hashset

> hi i noob to android, i try to display the color from the database using rgb color code, i used hashmap for map the data and field the data will come but i have rgb color code in db it will come correctly my problem is it will only display the last color value from db.. how to get all value and color fix to in text field..

```
public class AndroidJSONParsingActivity extends Activity {
static String items;
static String items1;
static String dates;
static String finalDate;
int a,r,g,b;
ListView lv2;
TextView text1;
String COLOR;
private static final String TAG_JSONDataResult = "JSONDataResult";  
private static final String TAG_GRPNAME = "GRPNAME";
private static final String TAG_QNT = "QTY";
private static final String TAG_BUDGET = "BUDGET";
private static final String TAG_STOCK = "STOCK";
private static final String TAG_DIFF = "DIFF";
private static final String TAG_DIFF_P = "DIFF_P";

private static final String TAG_COLOR = "COLOR";


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    lv2=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    Bundle b=this.getIntent().getExtras();
    items=b.getString("item");
    items1=b.getString("item1");
    dates=b.getString("date");

    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "yyyy-MM-dd");
    Date myDate = null;
    try {
        myDate = dateFormat.parse(dates);

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
     finalDate = timeFormat.format(myDate);

    torun();

}

public void torun() {
    String myUrl;
    myUrl = String.format("http://10.0.2.2:51382/RestServiceImpl.svc/jsons/?Location=%s&GROUP=%s&asondate=%s",items.replaceAll(" ","%20"),items1.replaceAll(" ","%20"),finalDate);

    final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    // Creating JSON Parser instance
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
     // getting JSON string from URL

    try {

        JSONObject json1 = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(myUrl);
        // Getting Array of Contacts
        JSONArray list = json1.getJSONArray(TAG_JSONDataResult);


        // looping through All Contacts
        for(int i = 0; i < list.length(); i++){
            JSONObject c = list.getJSONObject(i);

            String GRPNAME = c.getString(TAG_GRPNAME);
            String QTY = c.getString(TAG_QNT);
            String BUDGET = c.getString(TAG_BUDGET);
            String STOCK = c.getString(TAG_STOCK);
            String DIFF = c.getString(TAG_DIFF);
            String DIFF_P = c.getString(TAG_DIFF_P);

             COLOR = c.getString(TAG_COLOR);

            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            map.put(TAG_GRPNAME, GRPNAME);

            map.put(TAG_QNT, QTY);
            map.put(TAG_BUDGET, BUDGET);
            map.put(TAG_STOCK, STOCK);
            map.put(TAG_DIFF, DIFF);
            map.put(TAG_DIFF_P, DIFF_P);

            map.put(TAG_COLOR,COLOR);

            dataList.add(map);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    /**
     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
     * */
     ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, dataList,
            R.layout.list_item,
            new String[] {  TAG_GRPNAME, TAG_QNT, TAG_BUDGET, TAG_STOCK, TAG_DIFF, TAG_DIFF_P, },
            new int[] {
                     R.id.l2, R.id.l3, R.id.l4, R.id.l5, R.id.l6, R.id.l7}){
         @Override
         public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
             View v = convertView;
             if (v == null) {
                 LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                 v = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
             }
              text1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.l7);


             HashMap<String, String> map=dataList.get(position);
             map.get(TAG_COLOR);
             String[] ARGB = COLOR.split(" ");
             String V1=ARGB[0];
             String V2=ARGB[1];
             String V3=ARGB[2];
             String V4=ARGB[3];
             a=Integer.parseInt(V1);
             r=Integer.parseInt(V2);
             g=Integer.parseInt(V3);
             b=Integer.parseInt(V4);
             text1.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(r,g,b));

             return super.getView(position, v, parent);
         }
     };

            lv2.setAdapter(adapter);

    // Launching new screen on Selecting Single ListItem

}
```

Comment: While pasting code, remove all commented code and paste only required one so that it is easy to read.

Comment: @AshishAggarwal thanks and sorry..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add hashmaps in contactList while set adapter using datatList?

Comment: plz provide complete code and one thing u get LayoutInflator service more than once depends upon getview calling plz used it as global

Answer (score 0):

Try to declare the Map outside the for loop and initialize it every time. This why you are continously get the same value.

```
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        for(int i = 0; i < list.length(); i++){
        //
        //
        ...
        //

        map = new HashMap<String, String>();

        map.put(TAG_GRPNAME, GRPNAME);

        map.put(TAG_QNT, QTY);
        map.put(TAG_BUDGET, BUDGET);
        map.put(TAG_STOCK, STOCK);
        map.put(TAG_DIFF, DIFF);
        map.put(TAG_DIFF_P, DIFF_P);

        map.put(TAG_COLOR,COLOR);
        //map.put(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE, mobile);

        // adding HashList to ArrayList
        dataList.add(map);
```

Comment: not working... i put map on outside the for loop and declare the string global but data is not came